# Crontab run monthly job at every startup/boot

Tags: linux, cron, fedora

I have configured a simple reboot server every 15 of month: `0 3 15 * * root /sbin/shutdown -r now`

[image]

So this command on old server work perfect, but in this new server from 03:01 (First reboot) after the normal job boot 0 3 15 * * crontab run reboot command at every start.

I have a server that after rebooting in 15/20 seconds reboots again and so endlessly, the only solution was to remove the restart cron.

Fedora 31 Server no update available, date on server is correct.

I have also tried to run this command: `0 3 15 * * root echo "das" >> /home/test.conf` for testing cronjob and at every start i have this file with this test, **bug** or?

**If this cron is monthly why run at every boot?**

Comment: What is the date in the BIOS?  Not a solution (I don't like arbitrary reboots), but if the issue us clock drift you could prrpend the command with sleep 600 and start it 10 minutes earlier to allow for clock drift of up to 10 minutes.

Comment: Its a vps with proxmox and date is correct

Comment: Ok i have tested with sleep no change, only the time if set 180 the reboot or other job start with 180 second of delay..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with `hwclock --systohc`